# ruby help me trace the outcome

Tags: ruby, byebug

How come the outcome to this is 'a' the if statement should completely be skipped tbh (it's falsey?). ? Being there is no str[i-1] on the first iteration, it should throw an error, but it doesn't? When i trace through the steps using ByeBug it does throw an error.. which I don't understand.

> lib/test.arb:6:in `longest_streak': undefined method` status' for [nil, nil, nil, nil, "s"]:Array (NoMethodError)
> from lib/test.arb:19:in `'

```
def longest_streak(str)

    current = ''

    longest = ''

    (0...str.length).each do |i|
        if str[i] == str[i - 1]
            current += str[i]
        end
        if current >= longest
            longest = current
        end
    end
    longest
end

p longest_streak('a')           # => 'a'
```

Comment: You have the answer already, but note that it would probably be easier to use `String#each_char` here, and avoid index shenanigans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, a negative index will traverse backwards. So `str[-1]` will go from the end of the array, which will be `a` since that's the only character in the array.

`str[-1]` and `str[0]` are the same thing in this instance, which is why the `if` condition is evaluated, because `i` is only ever 0 and `0 - 1 == -1`.

You could work around this by adding a check to your conditional

```
if !(i - 1).negative? && str[i] == str[i - 1]
  current += str[i]
end
```

Comment: Seems, like I have a ways to go on this journey. I know -1 usually grabs the last index in ruby (which is awesome.) Thats basically whats happening? It's evaluating if a == a making the if statement true.

Comment: Correct. `str[0]` is `a` and `str[-1]` is `a`, so your conditional evaluates to `true`